# XPath to select preceding element with optional intervening whitespace-only text node

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Given an element as context I want to select the preceding sibling element and check to see if it has a particular name. The caveat is that I do not want to select it if there is an intervening text node that has non-whitespace content.

For example, given this XML document…

```xml
<r>
  <a>a1</a><a>a2</a>
   b
  <a>a3</a>
    <a>a4</a>
  <b/>
  <a>a5</a>
</r>
```

…then:

- For "a1" there should be no match (there is no `<a>` sibling element immediately preceding it)
- For "a2" then "a1" should be matched (there is no intervening text node)
- For "a3" there should be no match (there is an intervening text node with non-whitespace contents)
- For "a4" then "a3" should be matched (the intervening text node is only whitespace)
- For "a5" there should be no match (the preceding sibling element is not an `<a>`).

---

I can check to see if the preceding sibling is an `<a>` with `preceding-sibling::*[1][name()="a"]`

However, I can't figure out how to say "select the following sibling node, regardless of element or textness, and see if that's not text or `normalize-space(.)=""`. My best guess was this:

```
preceding-sibling::*[1][name()="a"][following-sibling::node()[1][not(text()) or normalize-space(.)=""]]
```

…but that appears to have no effect.

---

Here's my test Ruby file:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xpath = 'preceding-sibling::*[1][name()="a"][following-sibling::node()[1][not(text()) or normalize-space(.)=""]]'
fragment = Nokogiri::XML.fragment '<a>a1</a><a>a2</a> b <a>a3</a> <a>a4</a> <b/> <a>a5</a>'    

fragment.css('a').each{ |a| p [a.text,a.xpath(xpath).to_s] }
#=> ["a1", ""]
#=> ["a2", ""]
#=> ["a3", "<a>a2</a>"]
#=> ["a4", "<a>a3</a>"]
#=> ["a5", ""]
```

The result for "a2" and "a3" are what is wrong and confuses me. It finds the preceding `<a>` correctly, but then does not correctly verify that the first following-sibling of that is either not text (which should allow "a2" to find "a1") or that it is whitespace only (which should prevent "a3" from finding "a2".

---

**Edit**: Here's the XPath I was writing, and what I intended it to do:

- `preceding-sibling::*[1][name()="a"]…` - find the first preceding element, and ensure that it is an `<a>`. *This appears to be working as desired.*

  - `[following-sibling::node()[1][…]]` - ensure that the first following node (of the found preceding `<a>`) matches some conditions

    - `not(text()) or normalize-space(.)=""` - ensure that this following node is either not a text node, or that the normalized space of it is empty

Comment: I know that I can do this with a combination of Ruby + XPath, but I'm trying to find the XPath-only solution.

Comment: You sure ask hard questions. :-)

Comment: One problem is here: `not(text()) or normalize-space(.)="" ` must be: `not(self::text()) or normalize-space(.)="" `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/a/preceding-sibling::node()
       [not(self::text()[not(normalize-space())])]
            [1]
              [self::a]
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
       "/*/a
          /preceding-sibling::node()
                      [not(self::text()[not(normalize-space())])]
                                        [1]
                                         [self::a]
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<r>
  <a>a1</a><a>a2</a>
   b
  <a>a3</a>
    <a>a4</a>
  <b/>
  <a>a5</a>
</r>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the nodes that are selected by this evaluation, are copied to the output**:

```
<a>a1</a>
<a>a3</a>
```

**Update**:

What is wrong with the XPath expression in the question?

**The problem is here**:

```
[not(text()) or normalize-space(.)='']
```

This tests if the context node doesn't have a text node *child*.

But the OP wants to test if the context node *is* a text node.

**Solution**:

**Replace the above with**:

```
[not(self::text()) or normalize-space(.)='']
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/a">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "preceding-sibling::*[1]
                      [name()='a']
                         [following-sibling::node()[1]
                                    [not(self::text()) or normalize-space(.)='']
                       ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Now this transformation produces exactly the wanted result:**

```
<a>a1</a>
<a>a3</a>
```

Comment: That totally works (or rather, the part following `/*/a/`, for my needs, since I've already selected the element). Could you explain what my XPath was doing instead of what I wanted?

Comment: @Phrogz, I don't understand your XPath expression, therefore I can't explain what it does. If you provide in your question an explanation of each part of your XPath expression, than I may be able to point out what is wrong with its logic.

Comment: Thanks; I've edited the end of the question to clarify what my intent was with the XPath I wrote

Comment: @Phrogz, I updated the answer with an analysis of your XPath expression -- the problem is discovered and a correction is proposed.